# Unable to download any new software because of Errors

Tags: package-management, libreoffice, apport

```
No `apport` report written, because MaxReports is reached already

These errors were encountered while processing:

 fontconfig
 libreoffice-core
 libreoffice-calc
 python3-uno
 libreoffice-gtk3
 libreoffice-gnome
 libreoffice-pdfimport
 libreoffice-draw
 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
 libreoffice-ogltrans
 libreoffice-writer
 libreoffice-impress
 libreoffice-math
 libreoffice-base-core
 libreoffice-help-en-us
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is just the tail end of the list of errors..there is a more detailed explanation of all of the above listed prior to actual list. Here is one of the detailed errors:

```
dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-impress 

(--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-math:
     libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.9); however:
      Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
```

Any idea why this could be happening? I've already fixed broken packages with synaptic.

It's funny because this didn't start until I was in the middle of downloading synaptic and then it was interrupted. Also, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to resume the installation process? Please add their output to the question.

Comment: Yes I've tried both and still get the same errors. I'm totally confused, and I'm completely new to Ubuntu so I am perplexed.

Comment: Now I really need help!! I deleted fontconfig and it wiped out everything except for this browser and terminal. How do i reinstall everything?? Gawd I'm such a newb.

Comment: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` will install desktop back.

Comment: Yes I did that but was still unable to do any upgrades due to too many errors so I ended up reinstalling everything from scratch and now everything is back to being ok. At least now I know what not to delete. Ill be more careful next time.